# How do I translate AVR GCC-style C inline assembly to Rust inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, rust, avr, inline-assembly

I want to translate some Arduino code written originally in C++ to Rust but this line of inline assembly is giving me trouble.

```cpp
    asm volatile(
      "     lds r16, %[timer0]    \n\t" //
      #if defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
      "     add r16, %[toffset]   \n\t" //
      #endif
      "     subi r16, %[tsync]    \n\t" //
      "     andi r16, 7           \n\t" //
      "     call TL               \n\t" //
      "TL:                        \n\t" //
      #if defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
      "     pop r17               \n\t" //ATMEGA2560 has a 22bit PC!
      #endif
      "     pop r31               \n\t" //
      "     pop r30               \n\t" //
      "     adiw r30, (LW-TL-5)   \n\t" //
      "     add r30, r16          \n\t" //
      //"   adc r31, __zero_reg__ \n\t" //
      "     ijmp                  \n\t" //
      "LW:                        \n\t" //
      "     nop                   \n\t" //
      "     nop                   \n\t" //
      "     nop                   \n\t" //
      "     nop                   \n\t" //
      "     nop                   \n\t" //
      "     nop                   \n\t" //
      "     nop                   \n\t" //
      //"   nop                   \n\t" //
      "LBEND:                     \n\t" //
    :
    : [timer0] "i" (&TCNT0),
      [toffset] "i" ((uint8_t)DEJITTER_OFFSET),
      [tsync] "i" ((uint8_t)DEJITTER_SYNC)
    : "r30", "r31", "r16", "r17");
```

my best attempt is this:

```rust
    const TCNT0: *mut u8 = 70 as *mut u8;
    const DEJITTER_OFFSET: u8 = 1;
    const DEJITTER_SYNC: i8 = -2;

    asm!(
"     lds r16, %[timer0]
\t     subi r16, %[tsync]
\t     andi r16, 7
\t     call TL
\tTL:
\t     pop r31
\t     pop r30
\t     adiw r30, (LW-TL-5)
\t     add r30, r16
\t     ijmp
\tLW:
\t     nop
\t     nop
\t     nop
\t     nop
\t     nop
\t     nop
\t     nop
\tLBEND:
\t"
    :
    : "{timer0}"(&TCNT0),
      "{toffset}"(DEJITTER_OFFSET),
      "{tsync}"(DEJITTER_SYNC)
    : "r30", "r31", "r16": "volatile");
```

I'm still far from being able to compile. The error shown when I try to compile is:

```
error: couldn't allocate input reg for constraint '{timer0}'
  --> /home/kirbylife/Proyectos/rvgax/src/lib.rs:53:9
   |
53 | /         asm!(
54 | | r"     lds r16, ${timer0}
55 | |      subi r16, ${tsync}
56 | |      andi r16, 7
...  |
77 | |       "{tsync}"(DEJITTER_SYNC)
78 | |     : "r30", "r31", "r16": "volatile");
   | |_______________________________________^
```

I'm using Cargo and rustc 1.38.0.

Comment: Note that Rust `asm!` macro is [being revamped](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2873). On a more recent compiler, the macro you are trying to use is called `llvm_asm!`.

Comment: I'm not using the most recent version of Rust, so, I don't have the macro `llvm_asm!` available.

Comment: I just thought I'd mention that you approach might not be future-proof. Unfortunately I can't help with the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate meaning of your error is that there's not registers called `timer0`, `toffset`, and `tsync`. The root cause is that `"{}"` syntax in Rust denotes register names for constraints, not symbolic names. In other words, it corresponds to the `""` stuff in GCC, not the `[]` stuff. I don't see a way to use symbolic names, so just switch to numerical ones instead. Also, it uses `$` instead of `%` for substituting from constraints. Try this instead:

```rust
    const TCNT0: *mut u8 = 70 as *mut u8;
    const DEJITTER_OFFSET: u8 = 1;
    const DEJITTER_SYNC: i8 = -2;

    asm!(
"     lds r16, $0
\t     subi r16, $2
\t     andi r16, 7
\t     call TL
\tTL:
\t     pop r31
\t     pop r30
\t     adiw r30, (LW-TL-5)
\t     add r30, r16
\t     ijmp
\tLW:
\t     nop
\t     nop
\t     nop
\t     nop
\t     nop
\t     nop
\t     nop
\tLBEND:
\t"
    :
    : "i"(&TCNT0),
      "i"(DEJITTER_OFFSET),
      "i"(DEJITTER_SYNC)
    : "r30", "r31", "r16": "volatile");
```

(note: untested, since I don't currently have AVR-Rust installed)

Comment: `[timer0]` in the GNU C isn't a register name either, it's just a symbolic name you can use instead of `%0`.  The way the OP translated it (putting it inside the constraint string) is obviously wrong, but are you also saying Rust doesn't have an equivalent for that, forcing you to use numbers?

Comment: @PeterCordes I was trying to say just the latter (I don't see an equivalent in https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/library-features/llvm-asm.html); I didn't mean to imply that `[timer0]` was a register. What I meant was that the transliteration to Rust was incorrect because it assumed it was.

Comment: I didn't think you were imply that, but you do somewhat imply the OP thought that.  Didn't seem like the clearest way to explain that they dropped the wrong part of the GNU C constraint (the actual constraint instead of the symbolic name).  I'd assume they didn't understand what the GNU C syntax meant either.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see what you mean now. I edited it to try to make it a bit more clear.